# System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm appending string variable text, after appending a line throws **System.OutOfMemoryException**? 
Can any one explain why it is throwing error.

```
 str+="something  Text"

 str+="something  Text"
```

and lastly I assign it to a `lable` text

When I assign the value of `str` it throws exception.....

Comment: This single line looks fine. Please provide a *complete* example. Take your program, *remove as much as possible from it*, and then post the *smallest complete* program that reproduces the error you are seeing.

Comment: sorry i cant post the code.Posting can create issue for me..........

Comment: Is there any chance of an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: I think you should use `stringbuilder` for appending text....

Comment: @Vikky: even if there's no way for you to actually post the code, you should take the time to try to reduce it down to as small as you can get it.  If nothing else, it will help YOU decide where the problem lies.  And you might end up with a small enough sample that whatever prevents you from posting would allow it.

Comment: Then don't post your real code, but a small, artificial example that shows the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're trying to concatenate a lot of strings. Each time you change/concat strings a new string will be produced, because string is an immutable type.

Try using StringBuider to get your big-big string :)

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("something  Text");
builder.Append("something  else");
builder.Append("etc.");
builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems:

1. You probably shouldn't be using `<asp:Label>` for the thing you're doing. Try `<asp:Literal>` instead or provide us with more information on exactly why you're using a label and what it is you want to accomplish (visually, or in HTML terms).
2. You should build your string with `System.Text.StringBuilder` and not concatenate it with `+=`. This will improve performance and reduce memory usage, but since your exception seems to be occurring on `label.Text = str;`, just replacing the concatenation with `StringBuilder` won't solve the problem.

Say you have this ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:Label id="MyLabel" runat="server" />
```

and this C# codebehind:

```
string str = String.Empty;
str += "Some text "
str += "some more text";
MyLabel.Text = str;
```

Try to replace both of these with:

```
<asp:Literal id="MyLiteral" runat="server" />
```

and

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Some text ");
sb.Append("some more text");
MyLiteral.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Another option is to write directly to the output stream with `Response.Write()`. Without knowing exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish and why you have such a large string that you end up with an `OutOfMemoryException`, it's hard to help you any further than this, I'm afraid.